# Entity Framework 5.0 Identifier must be declared error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using EF 5.0 in ASP.NET, when i execute my stored procedure through OLEDB it returns value but when I try to execute the same through Entity Framework, I am getting oracle error as
    `ORA-06550: PLS-00201: identifier 'userid' must be declared`
Please help to solve the issue. Posting below my EF code.

```
Try
Dim db As New Entities

Dim param1 As OracleParameter = New OracleParameter("userid", OracleDbType.Varchar2)
Dim param2 As OracleParameter = New OracleParameter("pass", OracleDbType.Varchar2)
Dim param3 As OracleParameter = New OracleParameter("role", OracleDbType.Varchar2)
Dim param4 As OracleParameter = New OracleParameter("location", OracleDbType.Varchar2)

param1.Value = text1.value
param2.Value = text2.value

param1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
param2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
param3.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
param4.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("BEGIN LOGIN_PROC(userid,pass,role,location); END;", param1, param2, param3, param4)

Dim test = param3.Value.ToString
Catch ex As Exception

end Try
```

Comment: I'm not used to Oracle + EF, but is the `BEGIN-END` required? It looks like it pushes the variable declaration out of scope.

Comment: I'm not aware about oracle, but did you try something like (mssql) : `BEGIN LOGIN_PROC({0},{1},{2},{3}); END`

Comment: Yes.. I tried above.. Begin-End is not a problem. it gives same error if we not include Begin-End.. Anyhow, I will try until i find solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of search I found an article in Oracle community..
  https://community.oracle.com/thread/2228825?tstart=0,  where Graeme's solution works for me.

I completely removed the above annoying code and followed Graeme's and got it work.

The solution is simple and only 3 lines of code and have to use `Add Function to Import` in Entity Framework 5.0 with no return value and after that its work like a charm...

For those who have same issue, I am posting my code here...

```
  Dim Param1 = New ObjectParameter("role", GetType(String))
        Dim Param2 = New ObjectParameter("location", GetType(String))

        db.LOGIN_FUNC(text1.value,text2.value, Param1, Param2)
  Dim Role = Param1.Value
  Dim Location = Param2.Value
```

Really I searched more than 4 hours and finally I got it.  Also I would like to thank Graeme (Stackflow Member)
..